# Writing Codeception CLI test; want to throw exception but not have it fail the test

Tags: codeception

I forked Codeception/Codeception and added a Command module check that throws an exception.
When testing, this exception causes the test to fail but I'm running a test to force the exception and failure, to make sure it catches it.

Here's the edit to src/Codeception/Command/GenerateSuite.php

```
    if ($this->containsInvalidCharacters ($suite)) {
        throw new \Exception("Suite name '{$suite}' contains invalid characters. ([A-Za-z0-9_]).");
    }
```

When updating tests/cli/GenerateSuiteCept.php when I run the command `$I->executeCommand('generate:suite invalid-suite');` it fails because I'm throwing the exception in src/Codeception/Command/GenerateSuite.php in the first place.

Here is the addition to tests/cli/GenerateSuiteCept.php:

```
$I->executeCommand('generate:suite invalid-dash-suite');
```

When I run it, it says it failed. However, I want it to pass because I'm deliberately adding the dash to verify it catches invalid characters. What is the best way to do that? I'm wary of a try/catch block in these tests. I'm not sure if that is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the other Codeception tests, I found this to be a better way than throwing an exception:

```
if ($this->containsInvalidCharacters ($suite)) {
    $output->writeln("<error>Suite name '{$suite}' contains invalid characters. ([A-Za-z0-9_]).</error>");
    return;
}
```

So I modified the test to:

```
$I->expect ('suite is not created due to dashes');
$I->executeCommand('generate:suite invalid-dash-suite');
$I->seeInShellOutput('contains invalid characters');
```